# HOW TO SOLVE THIS ERROR FLUTTER A.S. PROJECT:- " A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > org/gradle/initialization/BuildCompletionListener"

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When i run the project there is this error:

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > org/gradle/initialization/BuildCompletionListener

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

First check the `settings.gradle` , must find project info like this:

```
rootProject.name = "InternalLibsKotlin"
include ':app'
include ':banner' // module
```

and then in gradle:app must see path like this

```
 api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 implementation project(path: ':banner')
```

Note that **include = path**